# geotools parsing kml with multigeometry only gives me first geometry

Tags: kml, java, geotools

I'm trying to parse the states.kml file (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/_downloads/states.kml) on the geotools website using the following code:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(new KMLConfiguration());
SimpleFeature f = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse( is );
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Collection<SimpleFeature> placemarks = (Collection<SimpleFeature>) f.getAttribute("Feature");

for (SimpleFeature fe : placemarks) {
    Geometry g = (Geometry) fe.getAttribute("Geometry");
    for (int i = 0; i < g.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
        System.out.println(g.getGeometryN(i));
    }
}
```

Each of the geometry fields for each placemark in that file is a MultiGeometry made up of a Point and a Polygon. When I run through my for loop and print out though, only the points are printed. Does anyone know how I can access the Polygon also? Is it accessible, or did it get dropped in parsing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it accessible, or did it get dropped in parsing?

No, it is very much possible to access any node in a KML file provided you don't miss out on the JAXB hierarchy: You may try something like below:

```
final Kml kml = Kml.unmarshal(new File("C:\\"YOUR DIRECTORY"\\Sample_2013_q3.kml"));
    final Document document = (Document)kml.getFeature();
    System.out.println(document.getName());
    List<Feature> t = document.getFeature();
    System.out.println(t.size());

 //for each loop for iterating through the folders
    for(Object o : t){
        Folder f = (Folder)t;

        System.out.println(f.getName());

        List<Feature> tg = f.getFeature();

        String folderName=f.getName();
        System.out.println(folderName);

 //Iterating through placemarks inside all folders
        for(Object ftg : tg){
            Placemark g = (Placemark)ftg;

 //check if the node under placemark is MultiGeometry
            if ((g.getGeometry() instanceof MultiGeometry))
            {

                 MultiGeometry mpg=(MultiGeometry)g.getGeometry();
                List<Geometry> gmList= mpg.getGeometry();
 //Get all the geometries and traverse them one by one
                for(Geometry geoItr: gmList)
                {
                     Polygon multiGeoPoly=(Polygon)geoItr;
                     List coordList = multiGeoPoly.getOuterBoundaryIs().getLinearRing().getCoordinates();

                      for(Object point: coordList)
                      {
                          System.out.println(point);
                      }
                   }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

LookAt tag changes LookAtx then parse success.
and geometry polygon get Property getValue() method.

```
    SimpleFeature sf = reader.next();

    System.out.println("\n## Feature : "+sf.getName());
    Collection<Property> placemarks = (Collection<Property>) sf.getProperties();
```

//          System.out.println("DefaultGeometry:"+geo);

```
    for(Property at : placemarks) {
        PropertyType pt = at.getType();
            System.out.println("Name:"+at.getName()+", Type:"+at.getType()+", Class:"+at.getClass()+
                    ", Data="+at.getUserData());

            if(pt instanceof GeometryTypeImpl) {
                GeometryTypeImpl gti = (GeometryTypeImpl)pt;
                Class<?> bind = gti.getBinding();
        }
            System.out.println("%"+pt.getBinding().getName()+", Value="+at.getValue());
```